# Drupal 8 custom block shows up in block list but can't be added

Tags: drupal, module, drupal-8

I ran into a problem while creating a custom block. There are other block inside the very same module, which can be added and are working fine.

Here's the code (filename is TourLink.php in /modules/custom/custom_blocks/Plugin/Block/):

```
<?php
/**
 * Provides a block that links to /tour
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "tour_link",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Tour Link"),
 * )
 */

namespace Drupal\custom_blocks\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;

class TourLink extends BlockBase {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
    $output = '
    <span>test</span>
    ';

    return array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => $output,
    );
  }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Class annotations go at _the end of the documentation block immediately preceding the class declaration_ (see [Annotations](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.api.php/group/annotation/8.2.x)). I'm not sure, but maybe this is really important.

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't it though.

Answer (score 0):

Renaming the class (and the file of course) to LinkToTourBlock fixed the issue. Why, I don't know. Also, TourLinkBlock didn't work either. Sooo strange!